# Resharper structural find-replace failing after first match

Tags: resharper

When using resharper structural find and replace with the patterns below, the replace operation only happens for the first match, despite multiple matches visible in the preview pane.

One possible clue is that each match "FileName (line-number, char-number)" appears twice in the replace preview pane, although only once in find-results if a find is done with the same pattern. If the tick-box for the second match at the same location in the preview place are all unticked, then the replace operation takes place.

This happens with resharper 2022.2.3 running in VS 2022 17.3.6, and also with resharper 2022.1.2 on VS 2022 17.0.4.

Is there something wrong with my pattern, or is there an issue with resharper?

**find pattern**

```
public void $CombinatorFunctions$() => $_sortTargets$.Sort($_combinatorFunctionsComparer$);
```

**replace pattern**

```
public void $CombinatorFunctions$() => $_sortTargets$.Sort($_combinatorFunctionsComparer$, "####");
```

**target code**

```
[Benchmark]
public void RoslynGenerated() => _sortTargets.Sort(_roslynComparer);

[Benchmark]
public void ExprTreeGenerated() => _sortTargets.Sort(_exprTreeComparer);

[Benchmark]
public void ILEmitted() => _sortTargets.Sort(_ilEmittedComparer);

[Benchmark]
public void ComposedFunctions() => _sortTargets.Sort(_composedFunctionsComparer);

[Benchmark]
public void CombinatorFunctions() => _sortTargets.Sort(_combinatorFunctionsComparer);

[Benchmark]
public void HandCodedFunction() => _sortTargets.Sort(_handCodedFuncComparer);
```

thanks, Ian

Comment: Same issue here, it replaces the first occurrence then exits. ‍♂️

Comment: I raised an issue with jetbrains, and I suspect this is fixed in the latest version of resharper

Comment: Is it? I thought I was on the latest version. I noticed it does actually replace all occurrences in one file, but it doesn't move on to the next file.